# C++: Minimization Using Levenberg Marquardt to Solve for Two Variables

Tags: c++, math, least-squares, minimization, alglib

I am trying to solve this [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkNfS.png) using C++:

X and Y are both given sets of data.

X = [x1, x2, ... , xn], Y = [y1, y2, ... , yn]

a is a given integer.

The goal is to find a pair z and k that fulfills this equation based on the given data.

I am currently attempting to solve this equation using non-linear least squares with the Levenberg Marquardt algorithm and I am using ALGLIB as the library to implement it in C++.

The issue that I am having is that all the examples I see solve for one variable ([This one in particular](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#example_lsfit_d_nlf)). However, I am trying to find the best pair that fits the solution (z and k).

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RSahu where would be the appropriate place to ask?

Comment: Perhaps http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I scrolled down the page with examples you linked and I see also example with 3 variables there (lsfit_d_nlscale)

Comment: @marcin I'm not sure how I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: A few comments. These are mostly to help you think about the problem. (1) Is it a requirement to use C++? Python would be much easier. Scipy and Numpy are extensive numerical libraries. (2) When you say X and Y are lists of data, do you mean this is an approximation or equation-fitting problem? Are you supposed to formulate a least squares problem and solve that? (3) Aside from k, there is also K in your equation. I wonder if k and K are the same or different. (4) Is it a requirement to use the L-M method? There are many others, which might or might not be more convenient.